# A bump in the night?

Tags: riddle

A mute cry for aid
Hold me right and I will send the British
Hold me wrong and I will summon the devil
What am I?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

My Answer:

> The Number '999'

Reasoning:

> - Britain's emergency services number is 999.
>
>  - The Devil is related to the number 666 in western culture, which upside-down is 999.
>
>  - 'Hold me' might references a 'dumb-phone', which when held upside down will flip the 9's, and although a call to '666' won't be summoning the devil it won't be summoning the British either.
>  - This bares a striking resemblance to War Time Propaganda as someone has pointed out.

Comment: If your explanation is right, your answer is wrong :P

Comment: @Aleeeeee lol i see what u mean XD

Comment: Yep, nicely done!

Comment: @tetris11 Ty, good puzzle.

Comment: That's not the [number I'm familiar with](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HWc3WY3fuZU).

Comment: @feelinferrety that number is stuck in my head now

Comment: Wow I can still recall this number in my head...

Answer (score 1):

Possible topic of answer:

> I think this could be related to WW1 or WW2. British is Great Britain, but "devil" could be Germany(German Empire) or Russia(USSR). But still have no idea what *mute cry* could be.

Comment: I suppose 'mute' was a bit unhelpful, maybe 'electric' would have been better